# Angular y .Net Core - No me trae los CLAIMS (Usuario no autenticado) - FrontEnd

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, entity-framework, backend

Estoy realizando una aplicación en Angular y .Net, la misma consiste en la elaboración de proyectos -como Asana- cada proyecto tiene un creador, así que ahí hice la conexión, relacione la tabla de usuarios y proyectos para crear la llave foranea (usuarioCreacionId).

Me cree un servicio para que me obtenga el Id del usuario:

```
  public string ObtenerUsuarioId()
    {


        if (httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var idClaim = httpContext.User.Claims
                .Where(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Single();

            return idClaim.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("El usuario no está autenticado");
        }

    }
```

Luego, en el controlador le seteo usuarioCreacionId al proyecto:

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] ProyectoCreacionDTO proyectoCreacionDTO)
    {
        var proyecto = mapper.Map<Proyecto>(proyectoCreacionDTO);
        var usuarioId = servicioUsuarios.ObtenerUsuarioId();
        proyecto.UsuarioCreacionId = usuarioId; 
        context.Add(proyecto);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Ok(proyecto);
    }
```

Esto funciona perfectamente en Postman y Swager, me setea el id y me trae los claims:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y obtengo la respuesta esperada:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando la peticion en Angular, no me trae los claims, y cae en el else de mi servicio en .net.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

error
:
"System.Exception: El usuario no está autenticado\r\n

Acá los llamados en Angular, metodo login y el post para crear un proyecto. Cabe destacar que el Login devuelve solamente un token, y ese token lo guardo en el localstorage.

```
  login(email:string, password:string):Observable<Login>{
return this.http.post<Login>(`${this.url}/login`, {email, password})
.pipe(
  tap(resp => {
    this.localStorage.getToken(resp.token)
  })
)


  crearProyecto(proyecto:Proyecto):Observable<Proyecto>{
return this.http.post<Proyecto>(`${this.url}/agregar`, {proyecto})
```

}

No logro ocomprender por qué me cae en el else de que el usuario no está autenticado, cuando estoy guardando el token en el localstorage y hasta usando rutas protegidas, los usuarios se crean en la base de datos y yo me puedo logear!.
Por favor si alguien me puede ayudar, gracias!

Comment: ¿Cómo agregas el token a las peticiones?

Comment: En el metodo del login lo guardo en el localstorage. Después utilizo un AuthGuard, si no hay token entonces no me deja entrar a crear un proyecto. Y funciona esa parte

Comment: Pero debes enviarle ese token a la api para que autentique la petición. ¿No haces eso?

Comment: Creo que no, lo único que hago con el token es guardarlo en el localstorage y ahí se mantiene. Cómo sería eso de mandarle a la API? Recién estoy empezando con esto, gracias